# How to use mathematical induction in case it seems evident?

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

I'm proving the statement

" det A where A = [ $a_{ij}$ ] $\in$ M$_n$(R) is defined as $a_{ij}$ = 0 when n+1 <= i+j "

and it should be proved by mathematical induction.

I know the answer since the last row of A is row of zeros in any number n, so det A is 0

The problem is that I have no idea how to solve with mathematical induction..

If I approach with mathematical induction,

Starting with n = 1) A  = [0] so det A = 0

For inductive step, when n = k , let det A = 0.

then, when n = k + 1,  and I should use the assumption that det A = 0 when n is k to show det A is 0 when n = k+1. At this point I have two questions.

First is I don't know how to approach inductive step.

Second is question about mathematical induction. Should I always solve inductive step from the assumption that it holds when n = k , although the situation n = k+1 can be proved without the assumption.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi ILias, welcome to Math.SE! Please format your post using mathjax to make it more readable, see eg the following tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference